# How do I display my own URDF in rviz?

Tags: rviz, urdf, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

This might be a dumb question, but how do I view my own URDF File in rviz?

My approach so far:

1. Create a new catkin package named "myrobot_description" with dependencies on the urdf package
2. Create a folder urdf in the folder myrobot_description/urdf
3. Create a valid URDF-File (as far as `check_urdf` is concerned)
4. Build the package with `catkin_make install`
5. Source the package by invoking `source setup.bash` in the install folder
6. Copy the launch files and folder from the `urdf_tutorial` folder to the `install/share/myrobot_description` folder (this doesn't feel right.)
7. Copy the URDF folder from the `src/myrobot_description/` folder to the `install/share/myrobot_description` folder (wtf, this doesn't feel right AT ALL)
8. Edit the display.launch file like this:

   ```
   <launch>
   <arg name="gui" default="False" />
   <param name="robot_description" textfile="/home/viki/catkin_ws/install/share/myrobot_description/urdf/myrobot.urdf" />
   <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
   <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="/home/viki/catkin_ws/install/share/myrobot_description/myrobot.rviz" required="true" />
   ```
9. Launch rviz via `roslaunch myrobot_description display.launch`
10. End up with a white block in rviz and Errors concerning a missing base frame

Now, as you can see, I just play around helpless and do not understand the whole process - but I do not find any ressources on how to craft a correct launch file or on "registering" my package or using rviz or which directory I should use for building URDF models etc.

I appreciate any help and pointers in any direction.

Thanks. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187815/how-do-i-display-my-own-urdf-in-rviz?/) by [MaxR](https://answers.ros.org/users/19715/maxr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right 6,7 steps not required.

After launching `rviz`, add `robot model` to rviz display and edit  `fixed frame` in `Global options` to "base_link" (this is the link name which you gave in .urdf )

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MaxR](https://answers.ros.org/users/19715/maxr/) on 2014-07-25**:
So, how do I craft a launch file then? Just create a new folder "launch" in the install folder and create a file "display.launch" with the same content as the one from my original Post? Or is there an easier, more streamlined way?

By the way, changing the fixed frame got rid of my white-box Problem

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-07-25**:
keep launch folder parllel to your src folder inside your package. Check this https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial hope will make things clear about folder structure and others

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2017-12-03**:
I created a video showing the process. You can check it here: https://youtu.be/yhcdc-8dStQ

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2022-06-03**:
@R. Tellez that's a 9 minutes long video for something that simple!